# How to execute procedure in APEX SQL script?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to understand how to use multiple procedures in APEX SQL script. First I don't really need stored procedure, but not sure how to declare simple procedure in APEX SQL script. So this is my attempt:

```
create or replace procedure test1 as
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
    dbms_output.put_line('test1');
end;

execute test1;
```

This gives me an error:

```
Error at line 7: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXECUTE"
```

So questions - how to create regular/not stored/ procedures in one SQL script and then call them. What is the entry point of execution in APEX SQL script?

Comment: Just to clarify. I mean `SQL Scripts` in `SQL Workshop` of `APEX`.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Sounds like a strange way to go about things, unless I misunderstand the question

Comment: I updated my answer, hope it will help now.

Answer (score 1):

**UPD** *(At the first time I understood question totally wrong)*

Correct version of a script:

```
create or replace procedure test1 as
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
    dbms_output.put_line('test1');
end;
/
begin
  test1;
end;
/
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35128/sql_rep.htm#AEUTL192) says, that script can contain inly SQL and PL/SQL commands. Commands of sqlplus will be ignored.

**OLD VERSION** *(Let stay here)*

In APEX pages you can use PL/SQL anonymous blocks. For example, you can create process (APEX has some types of them) or PL/SQL region, and use following:

```
declare
   ...
begin
   some_proc(:P_MY_ITEM);
end;
```

Here you can invoke any procedure and do anything else that allowed by PL/SQL. Also you can use parameters like `:P_ITEM_NAME` to get and set values of page and application items.

Comment: Yes, but my question is about APEX SQL script particularly, not pages. I want to use procedures in APEX SQL script. Writing anonymous block in APEX SQL script will run it, but then adding procedure leads to errors and I don't know how to call them.

Comment: Ohhh... I had made a little mistake ;) You mean `SQL Scripts` in `SQL Workshop`? As I understood, that scripts has to be like scripts for sqlplus.

Comment: No worries :) Exactly, I mean `SQL Scripts` in `SQL workshop`. So there is any entry point for that sqlplus scripts and ability to define/call procedures?